# what privileges do we need to grant to a user to access table constraints in public schema in redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have logged in as a non-admin user. information_schema.tables, information_schema.columns, information_schema.views, these are fine. The Problem seems to be with information_schema.table_constraints, information_schema.key_column_usage, they are not giving any data.

I tried granting select permissions on public and information_schema schemas to the user.

Answer (score 1):

In Amazon Redshift, not all users can view metadata about objects that they do not own. In your case, while you've granted the `SELECT permissions` on the `public` and `information_schema` schemas, these permissions do not necessarily apply to catalog tables and views.

In order to access `information_schema.table_constraints` and `information_schema.key_column_usage`, the user needs to have specific access rights for the objects that these views refer to.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO youruser;
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO youruser;
```

After granting these privileges, your non-admin user should be able to get the desired information

You can check out the official [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/redshift-iam-access-control-overview.html) for managing permission.

Comment: The issues is we can't grant the permissions you mentioned even if it works because we want that user to only have read only access to database.